# Apply grepl across columns by saving columns in lists?

Tags: r

I have a dataframe in the format mentioned below:

```
                  String  Keyword                           
1 Apples bananas mangoes   mangoes                    
2 Apples bananas mangoes   bananas                    
3 Apples bananas mangoes   peach   
.....
```

Its a dataframe (50000+ rows). I'm currently manually using the ifelse statement in batches.

```
data$Result<- ifelse(grepl("apples",data$String,ignore.case = TRUE)==TRUE,"apples",  
              ifelse(grepl("bananas",data$String,ignore.case = TRUE)==TRUE,"bananas",
               ifelse(grepl("mangoes",data$String,ignore.case = TRUE)==TRUE,"mangoes","unavailable")))


                String    Keyword Result
Apples bananas mangoes    mangoes mangoes  
Apples bananas mangoes    bananas bananas  
Apples bananas mangoes    peach   unavailable
```

Is there a way, where I could store String and Keyword in a list and then apply grepl on the entire list?

Comment: Please provide some example data and what the output should look like. If you have structures ready, you can use `dput`. See [this page](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) for more information on how to supplement your question with some dazzling fake data.

Answer (score 3):

I'm assuming this is what you want:

```
df <- data.frame(string=rep("Apples bananas mangoes",3), keyword=c("mangoes", "bananas", "peach"))

df$result <- ifelse(mapply(grepl,df$keyword, df$string), as.character(df$keyword), "Unavailable")

                 string keyword      result
1 Apples bananas mangoes mangoes     mangoes
2 Apples bananas mangoes bananas     bananas
3 Apples bananas mangoes   peach Unavailable
```

---

**Update**

Based on the comment, it sounds like you have a list of words that you want to check against the keyword. If that is the case, something like this might work:

```
#Set up toy dataset
set.seed(123)
df <- data.frame(Keyword = sample(c("mangoes", "bananas", "apples","lemons" , "peach"), 10, replace = TRUE))
df

#Choose your searchwords globally
searchwords <- c("apples", "bananas", "mangoes")

library(data.table)
library(stringi)
setDT(df)
for (x in searchwords) df[Keyword == x, result := Keyword]
df[is.na(result), result := "Unavailable"]
df

     Keyword      result
 1: bananas     bananas
 2:  lemons Unavailable
 3:  apples      apples
 4:   peach Unavailable
 5:   peach Unavailable
 6: mangoes     mangoes
 7:  apples      apples
 8:   peach Unavailable
 9:  apples      apples
10:  apples      apples
```

Comment: Obviosuly, data.table or ddplyr solutions will be faster.

Comment: Thanks for the help @Serban. I suppose I haven't framed my question correctly. The column **keyword** is actually arranged randomly. So the **result** column will return the keyword only if the exact match is found anywhere in column **keyword**, otherwise it should return Unavailable. I'm quite new to R and programming in general. So I apologize if i'm not framing the question correctly.

Answer (score 3):

Here's a simple and efficient solution with a combination of `data.table` and the `stringi` package:

```
library(data.table)
library(stringi)
setDT(df)[stri_detect_fixed(String, Keyword, case_insensitive = TRUE), result := Keyword]
#                    String Keyword  result
# 1: Apples bananas mangoes mangoes mangoes
# 2: Apples bananas mangoes bananas bananas
# 3: Apples bananas mangoes   peach      NA
```

---

Alternatively, a `data.table`-only version:

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df)[, result := Keyword[grep(Keyword, String, ignore.case = TRUE)], by = .(Keyword, String)]
```

---

**Benchmark**

Here's a benchmark on a `5e5` data set against the `mapply` answer. (The `for` loop answer haven't finished running yet):

```
set.seed(123)
df1 <- data.frame(String = rep('Apples bananas mangoes', 5e5),
                  Keyword = sample(c("mangoes", "bananas", "peach"), 5e5, replace = TRUE))


system.time(df1$result2 <- ifelse(mapply(grepl,df1$Keyword, df1$String, ignore.case = TRUE), as.character(df1$Keyword), "Unavailable"))
# user  system elapsed 
# 40.78    0.02   41.12 
system.time(setDT(df1)[stri_detect_fixed(String, Keyword, case_insensitive = TRUE), result3 := Keyword])
# user  system elapsed 
# 0.52    0.01    0.53
```

Comment: Except it returns NA instead of Unavailable, heh.

Comment: @SerbanTanasa that is fixable by just `df1[is.na(result), result := "Unavailable"]` which takes `.02` of second on my system. Which makes the overall running time from `.52` to `.54` which is `X75`  faster than your solution (on that tiny data- it will grow exponentially on a bigger data). The reason I left it `NA` is because `NA` is easier to manipulate and work with because of functions such as `is.na` and `na.omit`.

Comment: I'm a huge data.table fan. Couldn't get grep/grepl to work in it, nice to see your example.

Comment: Ok, Added a `data.table` only version which could be slower in case there are many unique `Keyword/String` combinations.

Comment: Interesting, in my benchmarks, the data.table-only solution is significantly faster. But yeah, that could change with increasing nrs. of keyword/string combos.

Comment: It will significantly change if the unique combinations number will be very large

Comment: Thanks a lot for correctly formatting the question @DavidArenburg and for the reply. I suppose I haven't framed my question correctly. The column **keyword** is actually arranged randomly. So the **result** column will return the keyword only if the exact match is found anywhere in column **keyword**, otherwise it should return Unavailable. I'm quite new to R and programming in general. So I apologize if i'm not framing the question correctly.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a version using 'dplyr' and 'stringr':

```
library(dplyr)
library(stringr)
df <- mutate(df, result = ifelse(str_detect(string, keyword)==TRUE,
  keyword, "Unavailable"))
```

Here is the line I used to create the play data:

```
df <- data.frame(string = rep("Apples bananas mangoes", 3), keyword = c("mangoes", "bananas", "peaches"), stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
```

And here is the output I get:

```
                  string keyword      result
1 Apples bananas mangoes mangoes     mangoes
2 Apples bananas mangoes bananas     bananas
3 Apples bananas mangoes peaches Unavailable
```

Comment: I wonder if you tried benchmarking this. I'm trying this on a 5e5 data set and it's running over 5 minutes now

Comment: No, I did not. It runs quickly on the (tiny) play data set, but it sounds like it runs into the usual disadvantages of `for()` on large data sets.